# python - path printed inside output

Tags: python, windows, subprocess, popen

I have a py file with this inside:

```
from subprocess import Popen

program = "path to program.exe"
file = "path to file used by program.exe"

p = Popen([program, file])
print p.stdout.read()
```

and when I do:

```
C:\>python file.py
```

In cmd I got

```
#output
#....
#... more output
C:\:>#...more output
#....
#...here finishes output
```

Why is it appearing "`C:\>`" ?
Is it because Popen in order to run the command I gave... needed to create a new process?

Thanks in advance

PD:
using windows server 2008
python 2.7.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The python script ends after starting the process, and your prompt returns (printing `C:\>`). However the subprocess is still running, and its stdout and stderr defaults to write in the console if not redirected, which continues to output and writes over the returned prompt.

What you probably want to do is wait for the subprocess to end, first

```
subprocess.call([program, file])
```

(if you're just printing the stdout there's no need to do anything as that's the default.)

If you do need to access the stdout, redirect the stdout and use communicate.

```
p = subprocess.Popen([program, file], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
stdout, stderr = p.communicate()
print stdout
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer, using it in my python script does not show the path (C:\>) if I use communicate and then print the stdout. The problem is how I should handle the process (I should do another question for this), if I do this by using something via web (http://localhost:9292/process) and return the stdout to the browser, it only shows the output BEFORE the path (C:\>)